# can't see availability set in the backend pool in azure internal load balancer with "standard" SKU

Tags: azure, internal-load-balancer

Hoping someone can help here, is there any specific option i need to be aware off that will make the azure standard load balancer picks up (show) a availability set in the backend pool configuration?

Basically, I have created a AS and it has one vm (for now), and then I created the azure "internal" load balancer with Standard SKU but when i try to  create a bep it only provides an option of virtual network in the drop down list with respect to the associations.

I tried to create the load balancer inside the same RG as the availability set RG because on this site i read someone mentioning  this as a possible solution.

I have **no** problem picking up the same AS when i create the ILB using **basic** SKU. So I'm wondering what is needed to make this working for the **standard** SKU?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the backend pool of load balancer, you can directly associate to the AS, a scale set or a VM for a basic SKU LB. While a standard LB is fully integrated with the scope of a virtual network and all virtual network concepts apply. So you only need to select one virtual network, the VMs inside the VNET will show up in the drop list.

Note: Only VMs in the same region with standard SKU public IP or no public IP can be attached to this load balancer.

If you have not see the VMs in the drop list, you can disable the public IP address of VMs or attach a standard SKU public Ip address to your VMs, then try to add the backend pool to your standard LB again.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-standard-overview

Comment: Thanks Nancy Xiong - MSFT. I had no public ip assigned and i can see the vm in the list. I guess the confusion is when you do this with basic SKU, it has a drop down list and you can pick the AS, in Standard SKU it's just a virtual network and that's it.

Comment: Hi csaif7, I think I have not catched the point of your question before, so I re-edit my reply to make it clearer. If this reply may help others who might have the same confusion, you can accept it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks. the "key" is the scope of vnet applies to standard sku lb. Appreciated you taking the time and updating it. I'm sure others will benefit from it as well.